# Google Maps ExpiredKeyMapError with recently created API Key

Tags: javascript, google-maps, api-key

I just created an API key for using with my site, the map is going to just show where the company it's placed.

But somehow the map is loaded and then it self refreshed and shows the ExpiredKeyMapError in the js console.

Have you got any idea what it can be?

PS: I tried to re-create it from another account and remove any non google parameters from url generation and still not working.

Page is:
https://corporativo.androsol.com/contact/

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The API key you created is still there in console.developers.google.com > API Manager > Credentials, correct?

Comment: This is happening to me too, and it's very frustrating.

Comment: July 2017, still happening.

Answer (score 5):

For me it showed that Javascript Maps API was enabled, I had to disable and enable it again.

Answer (score 3):

I experimented the same error. I think this is because **Javascript Maps API** is disabled. To solve go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library and click in **Google Maps JavaScript API**. I found this solution at [ExpiredKeyMapError on newly generated API key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560859/expiredkeymaperror-on-newly-generated-api-key). Sorry for poor english. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using React who stumbles on this issue, let it be known that generating a new API key and placing it in your .env file requires you to restart your React application.