# ExpiredKeyMapError on newly generated API key

Tags: google-maps, error-handling

I have just generated an API Key to enable us to display a Google map on our website but I'm getting the ExpiredKeyMapError.  This is the exact same issue as this stackoverflow query from 8 months ago, but that has never received a solution: [Google Maps ExpiredKeyMapError with recently created API Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631982/google-maps-expiredkeymaperror-with-recently-created-api-key)

When the page first loads, the map shows for a split second and then it disappears, to be replaced with a grey box that says:

> "Sorry! Something went wrong.  This page didn't load Google Maps
>   correctly.  See the JavaScript console for technical details"

And when I pull up the console, this is the error message I get:

> Google Maps API error: ExpiredKeyMapError
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#expired-key-map-error
>   SCRIPT12008: WebSocket Error: Incorrect HTTP response.  Status code
>   403, Forbidden

and that last line just keeps repeating.

Any help much appreciated because I have no idea how to solve this myself.

Answer (score 34):

I had the same error after generating a new API key, but I had JavaScript API already enabled and everything correctly setup.

While searching for an answer and checking what else I can do, the key started to work. **So every single time you create a new key, be patient and expect it to work within 1-8 minutes.**

Comment: That's weird, Isn't it ?

Comment: Yes and no. Depending on their setup it can take some time to be effective.

Answer (score 22):

I discovered that it was not working because I hadn't separately enabled the Google maps javascript API.  Once I'd done that, the map started working a few minutes later.

Comment: OMFG this! I had enanbled Geo location API for my backend services, and stupidly assumed this was the same to be used in clients. Thank you! Was going insane

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that it was not working because I hadn't separately enabled the Places API. Once I'd done that, the map started working a few minutes later.

[image]

Comment: This Worked! thank you! Once enabling the APIs we must assign the key to those APIs for the key to work!